# How can I format a number into a currency value without php?

Tags: mysql

I have a value in my mySQL database `13148.70`. I want to convert it into a currency format:

```
$data = $db->query('SELECT *, ROUND((price), 2) AS price FROM data')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The result is:

```
13148.70
```

But I would need `13 148,70 €`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function money-format in php :[money-format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

The nearest you can do in mysql would be this :

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(FORMAT(price, 2)," €"), ",", " "),".",",") AS price FROM data
```

Comment: Isn't there any solution like `SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,"%Y") AS year FROM data` like for example `SELECT *, FORMAT(price,2) AS price FROM data`?

Comment: Your solution is giving me the result `13,148.70 €` But I would need `13 148,70 €`

Comment: Yes, it is working :) Thank you. I was hoping there was a solution which is simpler

Answer (score 1):

**Syntax**

```
number_format(number,decimals,decimalpoint,separator)
```

So in your case:

```
$data = number_format($data, 2, ",", " ");
```

More information: [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format

```
select REPLACE(CONCAT(FORMAT(price,2,'de_DE')," €"),"."," ") from data;
```